# Making PHP performant for concurrent requests

Tags: php, performance, concurrency, profiling

I have a website that performs well under low load, but not when the load increases. I did some profiling to figure out where I should focus my optimization attention. I first profiled a single page load, and then sent the same request ~100 times right after another to see how the profiling differed under load. The results puzzle me.

See below the timing for the function calls that took the longest under high load (the numbers are in µs). I would expect for instance `PDOStatement->execute` to increase when the load increases, but what about simple function like `preg_match` or even `require` some arbitrary file?

Can anyone shed some light on how PHP handles concurrent requests, and what I can do to increase performance under high load? I know I can set up load balancing to handle the situation better, but first I want to maximize the number of requests a single instance can handle.

The website is running on an AWS EC2 t3.medium instance with PHP 7.4.19 and nginx 1.20.0.

| Function | Called | Low load | High load | Slowdown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| php::PDOStatement->execute | 12 | 9 852 | 480 169 | 49 |
| Dp\Core\Session::Autoload | 410 | 3 232 | 263 928 | 82 |
| php::curl_multi_exec | 17 | 8 166 | 237 367 | 29 |
| php::preg_match | 527 | 499 | 181 408 | 364 |
| Dp\Module\Storage\Storage::Init | 1 | 66 | 144 099 | 2 192 |
| require::/var/app/current/Dp/Module/Agreement/Term.php | 1 | 47 | 140 709 | 3 003 |
| Dp\Core\Session::GetConfig | 63 | 775 | 136 412 | 176 |
| GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request->setHeaders | 16 | 585 | 114 558 | 196 |
| Dp\Common\Storable\Storage->__construct | 23 | 503 | 108 962 | 217 |
| Dp\Module\News\Comment::Init | 1 | 85 | 104 186 | 1 225 |
| Dp\Module\User\User->ValidateProperty | 5 | 45 | 96 116 | 2 129 |
| Dp\Module\Support\ModelSupport\Ticket::GetStaticUri | 4 | 82 | 92 189 | 1 127 |
| Dp\Module\Technology\Game\Message::Init | 1 | 44 | 92 133 | 2 084 |
| require::/var/app/current/Dp/Module/Event/State.php | 1 | 35 | 88 102 | 2 545 |
| Dp\Module\Support\TechnicalSupport\Status::AddProperty | 4 | 22 | 88 085 | 3 961 |
| php::spl_autoload_call | 413 | 1 770 | 86 923 | 49 |
| Dp\Module\User\EmailVerifier::Init | 1 | 74 | 84 162 | 1 143 |
| Dp\Module\Locale\Locale->GetGettext | 3 | 52 | 80 110 | 1 551 |
| Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_stats | 4 | 11 | 80 049 | 7 134 |
| php::array_filter | 27 | 1 297 | 79 336 | 61 |
| Total |  | 202 138 | 4 759 748 | 24 |

Comment: The CPU is probably at its limit slowing everything down

Comment: Most of the time your bottleneck is DB I/O, not PHP code (unless you are a big fan of nested loops or huge files reads without chunks). Also, you need a proper set of tools to debug anything: traffic consumption monitor, CPU loads info, RAM usage info, HDD I/O data, DB stats report, PHP/MySQL/Apache/Nginx/etc logs. The table above is useless.